# how can get paylod data when I using FCM in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

how can get paylod data when I using FCM in flutter?

I tried used this methods, but I still could not got the data...

where has issues?

```
void getInitialMessage() async {
    RemoteMessage? message =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
    print(message?.data["type"]);
    if (message != null) {
      if (message.data["type"] == "noti") {
        print("AAAAA");
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                PostDetailScreen(postid: message.data["postid"]),
          ),
        );
      } else if (message.data["type"] == "active") {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => PostDetailScreen(postid: '456'),
          ),
        );
      } 
    }
  }
```

When I go to postman to test, I will send this format

```
Future<void> sendPushMessage(String token, String body, String title,
    String postid, String images) async {
  try {
    await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':
            'key=AAAAm2nkpqg:APA91bH9l8kYkJqGyGnVJhUe4dmG5KeYVrErEB_vl7vhZDGBAgFGOYsyHguDna-SBeP8juVoTtLQ61aI61QZ-46JFwaR-8KPai7CT6n4-jRZFBIMOHEl1Ph',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(
        <String, dynamic>{
          'notification': <String, dynamic>{'body': body, 'title': title},
          'priority': 'high',
          'timeToLive': 24 * 60 * 60,
          'data': <String, dynamic>{
            'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            'id': '1',
            'status': 'done',
            'type': 'noti',
            'postid': 'Mi6Y3sE9E0uz4uAvQjwC'
          },
          "to": token,
        },
      ),
    );
  } catch (e) {
    print("error push notification");
  }
}
```

I can receive the Notification, but I have setting `"type": "noti"`. So when I click the notification message, it shoule be print AAAAA and Navigator to PostDetailScreen. But It's always open app then go to homepage....

Comment: Android or iOS or both?

Comment: both cannot received

Comment: The application is terminated not just in the background? getInitialMessage works only in terminated case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send out FCM message with this structure, here I use NodeJS Firebase Cloud Function, but the important thing is to add the second, options part:

```
await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, {
    data: {
        click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
        type: 'noti',
        postid: 'ulEdnFiEZxyyc33UNvJs'
    },
    notification: {
        title: 'title',
        body: 'body'
    },
}, {
    contentAvailable: true,
    priority: 'high',
    timeToLive: 24 * 60 * 60, // in seconds
});
```

After this, in `getInitialMessage` you should have:

```
message.data['type'] // 'noti'
message.data['postid'] // 'ulEdnFiEZxyyc33UNvJs'
```

Comment: what is a `admin`?

Comment: @Stanley This is how you call Firebase Admin functions from a NodeJS Cloud Function, `const admin = require('firebase-admin');`

Comment: I still cannot get paylod data.... I had updated my context, can you check it?

Comment: Check [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref). `content_available` should be set at top level for example. And I think `click_action` should be within the notification payload.